# Storing numpy arrays in Cassandra

Tags: python, numpy, cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra data modelling and I'm wondering if the complex data types `set`, `list` or `map` could be a way to store vectors (in many case, from Python, coming from numpy array)?

Should I just use a binary format?

I'll be storing scientific data coming in the form of scalars and vectors of "limited" length, ~1000 and matrices, typically 10x1000. Ideally the vectors should not be opaque, matrices can be opaque that's not a real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using any of the collection types if the data size is big, or the number of elements are huge.

I the case asked, IF I had to use a collection I would use a List due to performance considerations, and given that in sets, duplicate values will not be stored distinctly. But the best way to do this is probably via a BLOB.

Further reading on Collection usage: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSet.html